# Spacing issues when using acronym package within emph

Tags: formatting, footnotes, acronyms

I have some issues with the footnotes created by the acronym package, when I use one of its commands within or in combination with `emph{}` or `textit{}`.

See my MWE, which uses the `acronym` package in various ways. In combination with italic text, the footnotes are too close to the italic text.

Any ideas?

BTW: Never mind my messing with the footnote counter, it is to have the same numbers in all sections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\title{Spacing issues}
\author{Dohn Joe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Not using \texttt{acronym}}

A sentence containing CFD\footnote{Computational fluid dynamics}.\\[3ex]
%
Another sentence containing \emph{CCM}\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}.\\[3ex]
%
Another sentence containing \textit{CCM}\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}.



\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\section*{Using \texttt{acronym}}

A sentence containing \ac{CFD}.\\[3ex]
%
Another sentence containing \emph{\ac{CCM}}.\\[3ex]
%
Another sentence containing \textit{\acf{CCM}}.


\setcounter{footnote}{0}
%\acresetall

\section*{Emulating \texttt{acronym} by using \texttt{acronym}}

A sentence containing \acs{CFD}\footnote{\acl{CFD}}.\\[3ex]
%
Another sentence containing \emph{\acs{CCM}}\footnote{\acl{CCM}}.\\[3ex]
%
Another sentence containing \textit{\acs{CCM}}\footnote{\acl{CCM}}.

\section*{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{CFD}{Computational fluid dynamics}
    \acro{CCM}{Computational continuum mechanics}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The package `a4wide` should never be used in new documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\AC@acs` and add italic correction (`\/`) after the acronym. `acronym` in the end essentially does

```
\mbox{CCM}\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}
```

We want it to be:

```
\mbox{CCM\/}\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}
```

Full example with redefinition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\AC@acs[1]{% redefinition with italic correction at the end:
   \mbox{\expandafter\AC@get\csname fn@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}\/}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\emph{\mbox{CCM}\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}} \par
\emph{\mbox{CCM}\/\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}} \par
\emph{\mbox{CCM\/}\footnote{Computational continuum mechanics}} \par % << this
\emph{\ac{CCM}}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{CCM}{Computational continuum mechanics}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]